# How many elements are in each of the following sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $\phi$ be the empty set.

What is the cardinality of the following sets?

1. $\phi$
2. $\{\phi\}$
3. $\{\{\phi\}\}$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Note: A "group" means something specific in mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty set has 0 elements. However, the set comprised by the empty set has 1 element. Finally, the set comprised of the set comprised of the empty set also has 1 element.

Therefore, the answers are

1. 0
2. 1
3. 1

Note that in all cases we always focus on the outer set.  The outer set in case 1 has 0 elements, and in case 2 it has a single element, which is the empty set itself.  Finally, in case 3 the outer set also has 1 single element, namely $\{ \phi \}$, which is the set characterized in point 2.

Comment: Number 3 was confusing me, thank you!

Comment: I've edited my reply accordingly